# Prove that if a triangle has sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then it is a right angled triangle

Tags: geometry

I understand this may be quite simple but could anyone do this? Proof by contradiction is the method I'm supposed to use.

Comment: What class are you taking?  Which tools do you have at your disposal that you think might be helpful?

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure how to explain this but I do A level maths and only have a graphical calculator

Answer (score 4):

Construct a right-angled triangle with sides $a$ and $b$. Call its hypotenuse $c'$. Because $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (as supposed) and $a^2+b^2=c'^2$ (Pythagoras' theorem), it follows that $c^2=c'^2$, i.e. $c=c'$. This means that the original triangle and the newly-constructed triangle both have sides $a$, $b$ and $c$. Thus, they are congruent, so the original triangle was right-angled too.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma$$